# make an usb stick bootable and now cant remove the data

Tags: usb, live-usb

I've used (borrowed) an usb stick to install Lubuntu. Make it bootable using make startup disk and now it's not possible to remove those files.

I've tried a few solutions but nothing seems to be working, or just couldn't find the right one. Any help on this please?

**Terminal outputs**

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw '/media/santi/Lubuntu 19.04 amd64'/
mount: /media/santi/Lubuntu 19.04 amd64: cannot remount /dev/sdb1 read-write, is write-protected.

----------

rm: cannot remove 'boot': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove 'casper': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove 'dists': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove 'EFI': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove 'install': Read-only file system
...
```

Comment: no, I didn't want to touch it too much, cause its not mine. @user68186 fat32 with gparted would be fine?

Comment: @user68186 it's done. Thanks a lot. You might want to post an answer with a little expl :)

Comment: I am glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Format the USB drive FAT32

You can use gparted or gnome disks (`disks`) to get the job done. Everything in the USB will be gone for ever. But, that is okay, as you don't want to return the borrowed USB with a Live Lubuntu bootable system. You want to return it empty and clean.

## Explanation

When you created the installation Live Ubuntu USB using the **Startup Disk Creator** that app did not just copy the contents of the ISO file into the USB. It used the internal command `dd` to clone the file system inside the ISO file. This file system is called [ISO 9660](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660). It was meant to be for DVDs and CDs. Since DVDs and CDs are read-only disks, the ISO 9660 is a read-only file system. This is why you cannot delete the folders and files inside the Live USB. Creating the Live USB in effect formatted the USB from FAT32 to ISO-9660.

By the way, when you created the Live USB using the **Startup Disk Creator** everything that existed in the USB was deleted for ever. So, if your friend who lent you the USB had some files in it, those are long gone. Therefore there is no harm in formatting the USB again to FAT32. In fact that is the only way to return it to its previous state.

Hope this helps

Comment: wow that's a crazy thing ha, thanks a lot! nice writing style :)

Answer (score 0):

The error message fragment `cannot remount /dev/sdb1 read-write, is write-protected.` means that the USB stick has a tiny physical "Write enable" switch. Eject the stick and find it.

Comment: i've looked at it but couldnt find anything like that

Comment: The USB is write protected because when you `dd` an ISO image into an USB you get a read only file system called ISO 9660.